# CLIでの認証キー操作について

Tags: soracom

ユーザーコンソールの以下で操作できる、ルートアカウントの認証キーをCLIで操作する方法を教えてください。

- https://console.soracom.io/#/account/auth_keys

SAMユーザーの認証キーは`soracom user *_auth_key`で操作できることがわかっています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ルートアカウント(Operator)の操作となりますので、"soracom operator"以下のコマンドで操作いただけます。

<実行例>
$ soracom operator generate_auth_key > ~/.soracom/newprofile.json
$ soracom auth --profile newprofile
testing authentication... newprofile
authentication succeeded.
apiKey:...

Comment: 早速の回答、ありがとうございます！できました！